# How to upload an R package?

Tags: r, cran

Is there any standard process/flow to upload an R package to the CRAN repository?
How to make use of vignettes? Is it compulsory to have vignettes for uploading a package?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about CRAN repository policies, not programming.

Answer (score 2):

- [CRAN policies](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html) details the official rules.
- About the process and flow and how to, there is a nice entry point for thinking [packages/packaging](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/), by Hadley Wickham.
- Vignettes are not mandatory when submitting a package (yet useful and more and more common) and they are extensively described in [their section](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/vignettes.html).

Comment: You're welcome, if you need something else, just ask; otherwise you can mark the answer accepted so that it doesnt appear as unanswered.